# javascript expected expression, got keyword 'break'

Tags: javascript

why does the following code with ternary operator in Javascript raise a SyntaxError:

```
firstblock:{
a||b ? console.log(1) : (console.log(2), break firstblock);
console.log(3);
}
```

but the following with if/else instead of ternary does not:

```
firstblock:{
if(a||b) {console.log(1)} else {console.log(2); break firstblock};
console.log(3);
}
```

Comment: a || b requires assignment to a variable. EDIT: it does not.

Comment: @Mμ. no it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` is not an expression it is a statement. The ternary operator is used to evaluate an expression based on a condition. You can't execute statements inside ternary operator.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#Syntax) the syntax of ternary operator is

#### Syntax

> condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

Here `expr` means expression.

Think `if-else` as two different branches in which you can do everything which you can normally. You can execute statements(code which doesn't return a value) like `return;` `break` etc.

The ternary operator is a way to just return an expression(code which returns value). In this you are just limited to write expression.

You can't use statement like break after `return;` i.e `return break;` is invalid code in the same way you can't use statements in ternary operators.

Comment: I see. Thank you, I shall keep it in mind.

Comment: @cynoob2 i have explained it a little more. Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.